# Reading Data from Today Extension (NSUserDefaults) works on Simulator but not in Device

Tags: nsuserdefaults, ios8-today-widget

I managed to read data in a Today Extensions from the companion app with code like

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]  initWithSuiteName:@"group.cdm.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults"];
NSData *encodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"DataContactList"];
CV_DataContactList *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
```

with the corresponding writing code in the companion app

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.cdm.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults"];
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
[defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:@"DataContactList"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I created the app group and added in the Capabilities of both target (extension and companion app).
All is working fine in the simulator and data are passed as soon as the companion app changes them.

But when I run the extension on the device it cannot read any data. I got the
`<Warning>: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL` on the console log.
I tried to also generate provisioning profiles, with right appid and app group, from scratch but it didn't solve.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem...could you tell me something???? have you resole it ?

Comment: I'm still there with the problem... I'd post the solution in case I'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class file where you save your data in TodayExtension target > Build Phases > Compile Sources. You have add only the .m files in it. 
For example: 
If the data saved file is MyData.m check if that file is presented in Target of your project and today extn target.

If this doesn't work and any of you have already found the solution please add it so it will be helpful later.